# How do I restore authentication for Debian Lenny synaptic package manager?

Tags: linux, authentication, debian

My neighbor calls me to fix things when his cats walk on his keyboard and cause problems that he can't fix.  This time it happened while he was running synaptic package manager.

After the reload, when we mark the updates, everything is unauthenticated.  I have never encountered this before and have no idea how to recover.

Is there a config file I can tweak to fix this?

Edit: I've added a bounty to encourage some solutions.

Comment: What happens when you run `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` instead of synaptic?

Comment: my suggestion - to use aptitude, also, `aptitude install debian-keyring` and this question for serverfault or superuser

Comment: @JoakimGebart, I get a string of errors. Pretty much the same symptoms.  I could record some of those errors and post here, if you think it would help.  It mainly has to do with the server connection being unauthenticated.

Comment: You should post a snippet of the exact errors.

Comment: Lenny is so far out of date that you may as well upgrade it anyway.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, post that as an answer so I can show my neighbor that that is the best way to go.  I don't have enough to keep me busy on Sunday, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lenny is so far out of date that you may as well upgrade it anyway. It was released February 14th, 2009. In Linux years that's almost an antique. (And Debian only promises support for three years anyway.)